# Design Query - Pull data from a third party data source and show it on UI

Tags: sql-server, architecture, application-design, web-application-design

We have to design a system where we have an application which will show data. The source of data is a third party Db which exposes apis to fetch data out of it. We have our db - Sql server where we will store this data.  From the UI of the application , whenever we want , we can pull this data from this third party tool by a button click. Question is - whenever there is a button click to pull data, should the data from this third party tool first go and store in our Sql db and then we should fetch this onto our UI. Or data should be fetched directly onto UI first , instead of storing in DB first and then later on Save button click this should get stored in our DB.

Comment: This depends on how the data will be used in your application and questions should be answered first. Is the data clean from the 3rd party? Do you need to massage the data before inserting into SQL Server? How often is this data downloaded and stored? Should this download be scheduled and inserted into SQL without user interaction? Just my thoughts that come to mind.

Comment: @SS_DBA : User intervention is required to pull data. Data pull happens once a month to capture month long data. Lets say data is clean and no manipulation is required. Lets say data which is shown on the UI is read only.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following points

- Do you have permissions to copy this data in your database ?
- Do you even want to keep a copy of this data in your database ? (because the original might have changed from your copy, etc.)
- Can you afford to not have this data surfacing in your app when (and if) the 3rd party database is down ?
- Are you getting a performance advantage if you copy the data in your app's db ?